# Tune a model for precision for a particular class in binary classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, classification

I am trying to adopt a liveness recognition model from this tutorial (the code was not much modified, the model remained untouched):

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/03/11/liveness-detection-with-opencv/

For training the model (which was left unchanged), I am using a custom dataset much larger and versatile than presented in the tutorial. For the future application I am planning to use this model in, I need to tune up the parameters so that I get a close-to-perfect precision for predicting a real face. To achieve that, I have applied the simplest solution of adjusting the decision boundary for the probabilities – from default of 0.5 to 0.97. I am tracking the results while training the model on the dataset – I am using tensorflow.metrics for that:

```
# compiling the model and enabling precision and recall metrics
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer=opt,
    metrics=['accuracy', metrics.Precision(thresholds=0.97), metrics.Recall(thresholds=0.97)])

# saving the model checkpoint upon meeting the best value for precision.
model_filepath = args["model"] + "_checkpoint" + ".h5"
checkpoint_callback = ModelCheckpoint(model_filepath, monitor = "val_precision", verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')
callback_list = [checkpoint_callback]

# train the network with the metrics callback
print("[INFO] training network for {} epochs...".format(EPOCHS))
H = model.fit(x=aug.flow(trainX, trainY, batch_size=BS),
    validation_data=(testX, testY), steps_per_epoch=len(trainX) // BS,
    callbacks=callback_list, epochs=EPOCHS)
```

However, the problem is I get the desired precision for the opposite class – for the fake(spoofed) faces. That is, the precision for recognizing fake faces is close to 1.0, but not for desired opposite class of real faces (which gets higher recall instead): [training results screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpOzc.png)

I would like to get the same effect but vice-versa (that is, I want to achieve high precision for the "real class"). How could I achieve that?

Thanks a lot in advance!